# How to replace '05 Sentra headlight w/o opening the hood

Tags: nissan, headlight, sentra

My kiddo's car has a busted passenger highlight due to him rearing ending someone.  This accident has caused us not be be able to open the hood.  At this point I don't want to replace the hood, just the light.  Any suggestions on this can be accomplished?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you tell us the year/make/model of the car? Also, a picture of the damage would be helpful to let us know what you're dealing with.

Comment: 05 nissan sentra

Comment: You absolutely need to be able to open the hood. How are you going to change oil, check coolant replace windshield washer juice? Where are you going with this conversation?  What is the goal here?  Exactly how many miles on this vehicle? I’m seeing a $2400 repair here. What do you see?

Comment: at this moment I only want to replace the headlight to make it drivable.  In a month or two I will tackle the hood.

Comment: Regardless of when you prefer to tackle it, it's a safety issue IMO to not be able to access under the hood.